# Custom UIAlertView: How to prevent an Objective-C object to be released automatically by ARC or How to retain an object manually in an ARC environment

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-controls, automatic-ref-counting, uialertview

I have written an UIAlertView like class (GOAlertView) just to have the same functionality of iOS7 beta 4's well known property 'contentView', which has been removed in iOS7 beta 5, in an other words, I am trying to create a custom AlertView. But with Apple's UIAlertView its possible to have a code like this:

```
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"Are you good programmer" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No comments" otherButtonTitles:@"Ya", @"Hee :)", nil] show];
```

**Important:** Here I am not holding any strong reference of UIAlertView like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIAlertView *alertView;
```

rather I am using it on the fly. Not only that but also I can the delegate message as well.

**Problem:** But with my own GOAlertView (which is not a subclass of UIAlertView) I can's show my AlertView because it has been deallocated immediately. But if I hold the strong reference like above mention way, it works. But I can't use it on the fly.

I have seen an example from: https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView/blob/master/TSAlertView/TSAlertView.m

where the programmer says inside the method '- show' "$important - the window is released only when the user clicks an alert view button" and he is releasing the 'window' object by himself. But I can't do so, because I am working in ARC enabled environment, and I don't even want to disable it (my be only for the GOAlertView).

Can any one give an explanation or may be a same example to have a contentView like property...?

**simulated code:**

**GOAlertView.m is:**

```
#import "GOAlertView.h"

@interface GOAlertView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end

@implementation GOAlertView

- (void)show {

    UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController new];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];

    [self.window setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelStatusBar];
    [self.window setRootViewController:vc];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 100, 200, 160)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

    [vc.view addSubview:view];

    [self.window setHidden:NO];
}
```

and **GOViewController.m is:**

```
#import "GOViewController.h"

#import "GOAlertView.h"

@interface GOViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) GOAlertView *alertView;

@end

@implementation GOViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

//    [self setAlertView:[[GOAlertView alloc] init]];
//    [self.alertView show];

    [[[GOAlertView alloc] init] show];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

here, if I use

```
[self setAlertView:[[GOAlertView alloc] init]];
[self.alertView show];
```

instead

```
[[[GOAlertView alloc] init] show];
```

to present, I can see a purple color square on the screen.

Comment: you need to disable the arc in that third party classes(TSAlertView)

Comment: I am not using it (TSAlertView) directly. As I have mentioned, I am using my own class known as GOAlertView.

Comment: I don't think it should get released if you are adding it to the display list. Show us the code where you actually instantiate and show the GOAlertView.

Comment: I agree with Odrakir, once you show an alert view, it doesn't get released as it is retained by the actual view hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be, in your GOAlertView class, when you init the instance, (ab)use associated storage to have the object retain itself until it is added to the view hierarchy (after which point, the view hierarchy will be retaining it.) Like this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void * const AssociatedStorageKey = (void*)&AssociatedStorageKey;

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // Hacky retain self...
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, AssociatedStorageKey, self, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)show
{
    [super show];

    // Should be in the view hierarchy now and retained by that, so we'll release our hacky retain
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, AssociatedStorageKey, nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}
```

Do note, this is creating a retain cycle, so if `-show` is never called, your object will effectively leak itself and the entire graph of objects it retains.

Comment: it has helped... thank you @ipmcc you are simply great... but I am expecting other variations too.